# Hive: exception for a select but not for select order by

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a very basic table in hive, transactional, stored as ORC, 10 columns (including 2 timestamps), 40 rows.

If I `select *` from this table (via beeline), I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unrecognized column type:TIMESTAMP_TYPE
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getColumnValue(HiveBaseResultSet.java:428)
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getObject(HiveBaseResultSet.java:463)

If I select only columns which are not timestamp I get the expected result. 
If I select any timestamp column I get the exception.

If I `select * order by any column` I then got the expected result as well.

I am at loss to understand what's going on here, and could not find any documentation online. Any idea about what could the issue be?

Context: hive 2.1, hdp 2.6

Comment: can you issue the same query from a UI like Ambari and check if you get the same error?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala yep, same error.

Comment: what is the timestamp format?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Data is already in the table as `insert` went fine. Timestamp type is timestamp as far as I know. When looking at data, it comes out as e.g. `2018-01-16 08:06:25.722`.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your data type in the file is different than the data type of the column in the table in hive.
Most likely you have a string in the file and timestamp in the table.

Comment: I would agree with this if I could never see the data. But when I `order by` the exception does not happen. It is this inconsistency which bothers me the most.

Comment: If you can add the schema of the table and the insert statement for one row of the data may be helpful.

Comment: The minimalistic schema is `(name string, created_on timestamp) stored as orc bucketed by name into 1 bucket  TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true')` (syntax not guaranteed, on top of my head). The insert is a complex `merge` based on a avro table.

Comment: Avro cannot have timestamp value, so it's probably string in the file and timestamp in the table. try to do select cast(created_on as timestamp) from table this should work ...

Comment: The cast is done at merge time, and my question still holds: why do I not get an exception if I sort the data? I would be surprised if sorting adds an implicit cast.